# update top 100 rows order by Datetime desc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update top 100 rows of `sterms` table `order by datetime desc` along with `inner join concept`

Query is:

```
update top (100) sterms set st.code=cd.conceptid 
from sterms st inner join Description cd on st.str=cd.term order by datetime desc
```

However this is not working

Comment: You said "it doesn't work". What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use CTE to first get `TOP 100` rows from `sterms` and then `UPDATE` like this

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM sterms ORDER BY datetime desc
)
UPDATE st
set st.code=cd.conceptid
FROM CTE as st inner join Description cd on st.str=cd.term
```

Comment: works perfect! but why top 50 if the author wants top 100? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would think it's just a small error. Try this instead:

```
UPDATE TOP (100) st 
SET code = cd.conceptid 
FROM sterms st
INNER JOIN Description cd 
      ON st.str=cd.term 
ORDER BY st.datetime DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

you can write your query using subquery and then update your data.

```
update X set Code = conceptid From
(
select Top 100  st.code, cd.conceptid,
from sterms st inner join Description cd on st.str=cd.term order by datetime desc)X
```

Comment: Downvoting is a Stackoverflow plague. Never mind. *(I **never** downvote)*

Comment: @SQLPolice I never mind but if your answer is correct then it should not be !